# Hide Web Part based on Custom List Y/N Field Value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I would like an easy way to hide or show web parts on a page based on a value in a custom list. Example: Business Client Y/N - If the field value is yes then Web Part 1, 2, 3 is visible - if value is No then Web Part 4, 5, 6 is visible and 1, 2, 3 is hidden.

Is this possible or does someone have a sample script that can get me started?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Final Update

OP (Oiginal Poster) uses Hilbilly Tabs which merges all WebParts into a screen with tabs.

[image]

Main requirement was to hide some unwanted Tabs.
No need to hide the WebParts.

We did a 30 minute Skype session to basically loop al Tab labels and hide just the Label for unwanted ones with style.display='none'

#### Here's a hack that does work since SP2010 and hides WebParts

You say you have a **Business Client Y/N** Column, so based on that boolean you want to execute code to hide a WebPart DIV

The core Javascript is:

```
document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').style.display='none';
```

Where WPQ2 can be WPQ3 , WPQ4 or whatever WebPart on screen.

*Disclaimer: I am providing a hardcoded solution, if you change remove or reoprder WebParts you have to change the hardcoded values*

You have to check the HTML code to find the IDs you need; with 6 webparts on screen (in my SPOnline env.) they are:

Group 1

- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2
- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3
- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4

Group 2

- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5
- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6
- MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7

Now onto the magical stuff,

**You want to execute JavaScript code based on the Y/N Column in a List**

The programmers solution is to read the List, then perform the actions,
But that requires some programming, JSOM or REST or SPServices calls...plenty of blogs out there.

In SP2013 it was made a bit easier with (CSR) Client Side Rendering code, but it still requires about 20 lines of code.

**Think Different** *(I always love using this Steve Jobs quote in a Microsoft World ;-)*

### What if your **List-Item** could execute that code?

- If Business-Client = TRUE

  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').style.display='none';
- If Business-Client = FALSE

  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').style.display='none';
  document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7').style.display='none';

Again.. modern SharePoint 2013 Developers say: CSR! *(And still have to write 20 lines of code AND add an extra JS file somewhere)*

#### No! I said: Think Different

We are going to put the JavaScript **INSIDE** the ListItem,
**so it executes when the List-Item is displayed**

http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How explains how we can execute JavaScript in a Calculated Column

so the proof of concept Formula is:

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&"    document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').style.display='none';"
&"    document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').style.display='none';"
&"    document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').style.display='none';"
&"}"">"
```

- Create a Calculated Column with this Formula,
- set the datatype to Number!!
- And display it in a View...

3 WebParts (including your View) should dissappear

#### Go test if you are with me sofar, I will append the next steps in a moment

### Think Different - the Sequel

By now the above Proof of Concept should have hidden 3 WebParts.

Let's add the Y/N Logic

I hope you were smart enough to add the Calculated Column to your List with that **Business Client** column

All you have to do is add SharePoint IF/THEN/ELSE syntax, it ain't rocket science...

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
&IF(
    [Business Client]
    ,
        "document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').style.display='none';"
        &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').style.display='none';"
        &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').style.display='none';"
    ,
        "document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').style.display='none';"
        &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').style.display='none';"
        &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7').style.display='none';"
)
&"}"">"
```

**Cool! You now have a SharePoint Calculated Column generating "Dynamagical" JavaScript code.**

#### Final steps

Now you need to add a ListView Webpart displaying 1 ListItem at the **bottom of** the page where you want hide WebParts.

You may want to add an extra WebPartID so this WebPart executes the code and hides itself.

#### A Word on executing JavaScript from a Calculated Column

This code is executed the moment it is displayed, the rest of the page is still loading...

If any webparts are displayed later they will not be found. You can add a timeout (or any Javascript):

```
="<img src=/_layouts/images/blank.gif onload=""{"
    &"setTimeout(function(){"
    &IF(
        [Business Client]
        ,
            "document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ2').style.display='none';"
            &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ3').style.display='none';"
            &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ4').style.display='none';"
        ,
            "document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5').style.display='none';"
            &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ6').style.display='none';"
            &"document.getElementById('MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ7').style.display='none';"
    )
    &"},3000);"
&"}"">"
```

It is a real PITA to debug these Formulas, prepare/rework everthing in a decent text-editor then paste into SharePoint

Comment: I am unsure if this will work how I am trying to apply it, or, I still haven't learned enough yet. Where I am trying to execute this solution is after a user selects a client from a custom list and the display form is presented, on that page I have added web parts that display the related custom lists. Some clients are "Personal" and Some are "Business" I am currently using Hillbilly tabs to display the related lists in tabs. Will this solution work in this application or do I need to dig a bit deeper?

Comment: If the form that shows the web parts is different from the form where user makes the selection then you may have to pass that as query string to the form that shows the web parts! As i mentioned earlier, you may have to share your code to get better response from Danny. Also, i have a feeling that you may need a developer assistance to handle this. I voted for Danny's answer and I think it is cool though it can be done bit differently in traditional ways. Best of luck!

Comment: Since we are talking about javascript  calculated columns here, i tried getting SP.ClientContext on load of an image but it shows undefined . Any idea Danny (since I've seen you using this in calculated columns)?

Comment: ok so I have found the code on the page to identify the web parts and they are on the same page. So I am going to follow these directions and see how I make out. Quick question on the Calculated Column, maybe I missed it in the code, will it read the value Y/N from the Business Client Field?

Comment: ok I have added the Calculated Column and added a new record where Business Client = Yes - however when I go to that record the calculated column displays: #Name?

Comment: You did not get your motorcycle driving license after just one lesson (at least I did not), same applies to SharePoint. I say start with babysteps, learning the Calculated Column stuff is at http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/.   BUT... I fear you might run into another problem... it could be that Tab script you use is actually one huge page with a lot of WebParts .. but displayed on Tabs.. that would mean you need to get into that Tabs code.. that is serious JavaScript Developer stuff.

Comment: @Akhoy, SP.ClientContext is only available after page load... as I explained.. this IMG onload is executed *while* the page is loading. So you can use it in a onclick handler (see http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/Create/) or wait till the whole page loaded

Comment: Danny is this something I could have you look at and tell me the direction I need to look in or if it is really just me still learning and not quite ready for the races?

Comment: I fear the latter applies. We can do a Skype session monday so you can show me what you have now, contact me at danny@365csi.nl.. please take the timezone into account, I am in Amsterdam UTC/GMT+2

Comment: Thank you Danny for your time and solution! You rock! For everyone else, Danny was able to find a (in my opinion) simple way to load the tab labels in into an array and then hide them based on a field value. Here is the script:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know how to find the value in the custom list using JS, you can hide web parts as suggested in this post 
[How to hide a Web Part using javascript](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/3f19a180-a51e-4257-89ee-f2273035bb41/how-to-hide-a-web-part-using-javascript)

Comment: I am not sure how to add that to the script in the example you referenced. Can you explain how I would find the value and pass it to the script?

Comment: ah.. you're not a javascripter... I'll get back to you in 2 hours.. have an example for this on my PC at home

Comment: You can add content / script editor to your page and add this script there. I am not sure if you are showing the value of the custom list in the same page!?

Comment: No, I am still learning and wanting to help a client, I am a network admin thrown into the world of SharePoint but trying to learn as fast as possible. Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: What I am doing is using Hillbilly tabs to display multiple related custom lists on the same page, so in this case I want to display different web parts based on if the client record is marked as Business Client Y/N. So that business related tabs appear for business clients and personal tabs appear if they are not a business client. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I think Danny has a ready made code. If his code, doesn't work, I will give it a try! If the column 'Business Client' is displayed on the same page then there is a way to do it. If it is not, then you have to make a query (JSOM) to find out the value and hide / show web parts. Let Danny provide the code!

Comment: Also, it is worth to share your code. If Danny's code is not a straight fit, he will be able to suggest how to tweak his code to suit your needs. Please update the question to share your code. Thanks

Comment: I will do that,  thank you and thank you to Danny in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So one last update, Internet Explorer didn't play nice with the first version of the script so Danny was able to make a few changes and make it IE friendly. Again, many thanks to Danny, he was able to solve this. Here is the final version of the script that I have tested with all the major web browsers:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    if(console)console.info('executing hideTabs');
    var BusinessClient=document.getElementById('SPFieldChoice').textContent;//get Yes/No value
    var hideLabels=['Business History','Employees'];//default hides for No value
        if(BusinessClient.indexOf('Yes')>0){
            hideLabels=['Spouse','Dependents','Client History','MediCare','MediCare Reviews','ACA','Reports'];//hides for Yes
    }
    var arrayLIelements=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"]'));
    if(console)console.info('executing hideTabs'+arrayLIelements.length);
    arrayLIelements.forEach(function(li){//loop over all LI elements
        var label=li.textContent;//get the text label only, strip all HTML
        if(console)console.info(label);
        var display='visible';//default leave LI visible
        if( hideLabels.indexOf( label )>-1 ){//if the label is in the hide array
            display='none';//CSS hide
        }
        li.style.display=display;//apply the style
    });
    if(console)console.info('executed hideTabs');
});
```